# WPF Edit Templated Column by Code

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to edit the contents of an StackPanel inside a templated DataGrid Column by Code. Unfortunately i cannot find the StackPanel from Code. Can anybody help me, please?

This is my DataTemplate:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReservationContainerTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This is how I create this Column:

```
var colReservations = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

colReservations.Header = "Nordplatz";

DataTemplate dt = null;
dt = dataGrid1.FindResource("ReservationContainerTemplate") as DataTemplate;

colReservations.CellTemplate = dt;
dataGrid1.Columns.Add(colReservations);
```

What I need to do is, writing to this StackPanel inside DataTemplate.

Comment: A code snippet will be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the Object by following Code:

```
        DataRowView n = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.Items[i];
        //var m = dataGrid1.SelectedItem.Cells[0].Text;

        DataTemplate Template = dataGrid1.FindResource("ReservationContainerTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        StackPanel stp = Template.LoadContent() as StackPanel;
```

Great, I've got my Object, but how can I modify it? Under this conditions i've only got a copy of the Object, changes are not reflected to the original one.

Does anybody have got an idea?